# What is the name for the average of the largest and the smallest values in a given data set?

Tags: terminology, mean, range

What do you call a statistical mean that is calculated from upper and lower extremes in any given dataset?

For example, if you have a set:

```
{ -2, 0 , 8, 9, 1, 50, -2, 6}
```

The upper extreme of this set is `50` and lower extreme is `-2`. So, average of the extremes would be `(-2 + 50 / 2) = 48/2 = 24`

Is there a term for this kind of statistical mean?

Comment: It's the "midrange".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called the [midrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range) and while it's not the most widely used statistic in the world it does have some relevance to the uniform distribution.

Let's introduce the [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) notation: if have $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$, then the notation $X_{(i)}$ is used to refer to the $i$-th largest of the set $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$. Thus we have:

$$ X_{(1)} ≤ X_{(2)} ≤···≤ X_{(n)} \tag{1} $$

Where $X_{(1)}$ is the minimum and $X_{(n)}$ is the maximum element. Then [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics)) and [midrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-range) are defined as:

$$ \begin{align}
  R & = X_{(n)} - X_{(1)} \tag{2} \\
  A & = \frac{X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}}{2} \tag{3} \\
  \end{align}
$$

These formulas are taken from [CRC Standard Probability and Statistics Tables and Formulae](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Math%20Complete/Probability%20and%20statistics/CRC%20-%20standard%20probability%20and%20Statistics%20tables%20and%20formulae%20-%20DANIEL%20ZWILLINGER.pdf), section 4.6.6.

If $X_i$ is assumed to have a uniform distribution $X_i \sim U(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the lower and upper bounds respectively, then we can give the MLE estimates in terms of these formulas:

$$ 
 \begin{align}
  \hat{\alpha} & = X_{(1)} \tag{4} \\
  \hat{\beta} & = X_{(n)} \tag{5}
 \end{align}
$$

The mean of the resulting distribution is the same as the midrange:

$$ 
 \begin{align}
  \mu & = A = \frac{X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}}{2} \tag{6} \\
 \end{align}
$$

This is probably the only use for this particular statistic.

Comment: Historicaly, the mean air temperature of a day was given as the midrange.